# A little line appears at the bottom of AppBar when setting toolbarHeight property with a value

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to set Scaffold AppBar with the top widget of the body to the same gradient color. And AppBar height with a specific size uses the toolbarHeight property. But when I do it, an unexpected line appears between AppBar and the top widget of the body. I tried searching on the internet and found a solution to set backgroundColor property with the same color of flexibleSpace container widget, the problem is solved. But I can't use this solution, because I use gradient color for the background.
Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.amber,
      ),
      home: const CloneMyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

const LinearGradient appBarGradient = LinearGradient(
  colors: [
    Color.fromARGB(255, 29, 201, 192),
    Color.fromARGB(255, 125, 221, 216),
  ],
  stops: [0.5, 1.0],
);

class CloneMyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const CloneMyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 125, 221, 216),
        toolbarHeight: 100.0,
        bottomOpacity: 0.0,
        elevation: 0.0,
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            // color: Color.fromARGB(255, 125, 221, 216),
            gradient: appBarGradient,
          ),
        ),
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: Text(
                "My title",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
              child: Row(
                children: const [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                    child: Icon(Icons.notifications_outlined),
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.search),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [BelowAppBar()],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BelowAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const BelowAppBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).user;
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        // color: Color.fromARGB(255, 125, 221, 216),
        gradient: appBarGradient,
      ),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 10,
        right: 10,
        bottom: 10,
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
              text: 'Hello, ',
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 22,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              children: [
                TextSpan(
                  text: "Dung",
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 22,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the image (arrow points to the little line):
[The image shows an unexpected line between AppBar and first widget of the body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L72Qq.jpg)

Comment: Have you find the solution because I tried your code but no line seen. [link]https://prnt.sc/ztvpd94U3VZX

Comment: Thank you for replying, I have checked with another device. And it doesn't have any unexpected lines. I think the problem appears with my test device.